# Redirect AWS Elastic Beanstalk URL to my own domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cname

I hosted a website in Elastic Beanstalk with that url format: http://{appname}.elasticbeanstalk.com. A new URL is created in the format: http://appname.com. I want to automatically redirect to that new one. I can do that by means of codes but I would like to do that instead by setting it in Amazon.

How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to redirect http://appname.com. to the http://{appname}.elasticbeanstalk.com or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand... You want to redirect your `http://{appname}.elasticbeanstalk.com` to `http://appname.com`.
If you want to do it through AWS you can use the Route 53 service. In Route 53 you can choose a domain or you can bring your own.

Here is some documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html)  and [here](http://www.mikemurry.com/custom-domain-elastic-beanstalk/) that'll show you how to achieve it.

And a screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: You cannot set up above redirect using Route 53. Route 53 is for DNS and not redirects.

Comment: yeah, you can by adding a record set to an alias. I edited the answer and posted a screenshot.

Comment: Your above step will redirect http://appname.com to http://{appname}.elasticbeanstalk.com and not what you stated in the answer